# Want to create a stream of characters from char array in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

From a char array, I want to construct a stream to use java 8 features such as filters and maps.

```
char[] list = {'a','c','e'};
Stream<Character> cStream = Stream.of(list);
// Stream<Character> cStream = Arrays.stream(list);
```

The first method does not work (Reason: change cStream to `Stream<char[]>`).
The commented line does not also work (Reason: The method `stream(T[])` in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (`char[]`)).

I know that if `char[] list` is changed to `int[]`, everything works fine using `IntStream`. But I do not want to convert every `char[]` to `int[]` each time or change into a list when I need to use stream library on `char` array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is String.chars() a stream of ints in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8)

Comment: @heenenee That's certainly related, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Comment: Although the other question is focused on why, the how is explained in its accepted answer.  A single google search would've turned this up, and I guess I'm going by http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2646526

Answer (score 56):

You can use an `IntStream` to generate the indices followed by `mapToObj`:

```
char[] arr = {'a','c','e'};
Stream<Character> cStream = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 54):

A way to do this is via a String object:

```
char[] list = {'a','c','e'};
Stream<Character> charStream = new String(list).chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i);
```

I like to do it this way because all the complexity of transforming the array is wrapped into the String creation, and the wrapping of char is also performed behind the scene for me so I can focus on the business logic.

Comment: Semantically not different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649229/2711488), except that using `CharBuffer.wrap(list)` is more efficient than `new String(list)` as it does not involve copying the array resp., starting with Java 9, converting the char array to a byte array and converting it back while streaming. Under Java 8, the difference is even bigger as `String.chars()` has been poorly implemented whereas `CharBuffer.chars()` has an efficient implementation. That has been solved with Java 9, but the copying/conversion overhead of `new String(char[])` remains.

Comment: Note that sometimes, when you have an array of characters, it's because it's a sensitive value (like a password), and you're explicitly avoiding instantiating a String. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords

Answer (score 38):

A short and efficient way to create an `IntStream` from `char[]` array is to use `java.nio.CharBuffer`:

```
char[] list = {'a','c','e'};
IntStream stream = CharBuffer.wrap(list).chars();
```

This way you can use an `IntStream` interpreting the int values as characters. If you want a boxed `Stream<Character>` (which may be less efficient), use

```
Stream<Character> stream = CharBuffer.wrap(list).chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch);
```

Using `CharBuffer` can be a little bit faster than `IntStream.range` as it has custom spliterator inside, so it does not have to execute an additional lambda (possibly as slow polymorphic call). Also it refers to the `char[]` array only once and not inside the lambda, so it can be used with non-final array variable or function return value (like `CharBuffer.wrap(getCharArrayFromSomewhere()).chars()`).

Comment: I really like that solution since it doesn't copy the elements of array while still avoiding autoboxing.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest change you can make to the code is change `char[]` to `Character[]`.

Another way is to create a new ArrayList of the boxed `char`s:

```
char[] list = {'a','c','e'};
List<Character> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c : list)
    listArray.add(c);
Stream<Character> cStream = listArray.stream();
```

In addition, you can use Google Guava's [`Chars`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html) class, to replace the `for` loop with:

```
List<Character> listArray = Chars.asList(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way not mentioned: make a `new String`

```
char[] arr = {'a','c','e'};
new String(arr).chars().mapToObj(i -> (Character) (char) i);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Getting substream of Characters**

```
 String givenString = "MyNameIsArpan";

       Object[] ints = givenString.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).toArray();

       String subString = Arrays.stream(ints,2,6).
                             map(i -> (char)i).
                             map(String::valueOf).
                             collect(Collectors.joining());

      System.out.println(subString);
```

OUTPUT : Name

Answer (score 1):

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a workaround:
char[] list = {'a','c','e'};

Arrays.asList(list).stream();

Answer (score 0):

Using Stream Builder:

```
String inputString = "This is string";
Stream.Builder<Character> charStreamBuilder = Stream.builder();
for (char i :inputString.toCharArray()) {
   charStreamBuilder.accept(i);
 }
 Stream<Character> characterStream = charStreamBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score -6):

I believe the simplest way to convert to Character stream is

```
    char[] list = {'a','c','e'};

    Stream<Character> characters = Stream.ofAll(list);
```

Comment: Although interesting, this answer is not valid because the question is about JDK Steams, and it seems you are referring to javaslang streams.

Comment: If someone needs to know, he is referring to the www.vavr.io