# count the frequency of each character in char array using java 8 stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

given

```
char[] arr = {'a','a','c','d','d','d','d'};
```

i want to print like this
`{a=2,c=1,d=4}`  using java 8 streams.

using this :

```
Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is `Stream.of(char[])` returns a Stream where each element is an array of char, you want a stream of char, there is several methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554025/want-to-create-a-stream-of-characters-from-char-array-in-java)

```
char[] arr = {'a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'};

Map<Character, Long> result = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result); // {a=2, c=1, d=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CharFrequencyCheck {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Character> charArray = Stream.of('a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd');
    Map<Character, Long> result1 = charArray.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(result1);
}
```

} // this can be helpful as well :)