# How To Count Occurrences Of Each Character In String In Java 8(lambda exp or streams) but not in traditional method?

Tags: java-8

> Sample output All Is Well : { =2, A=1, s=1, e=1, W=1, I=1, l=4}

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: I know how to do it in normal way like using map but using lambda or streams (java-8) I don't have idea

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70224399/160256

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
    Arrays.stream("inputstring".split(""))
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " = " + v));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unordered:

```
"All Is Well"
    .chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("'" + k + "' = " + v));
```

Alphabetically ordered & lowercased:

```
"All Is Well"
    .chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
    .map(Character::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("'" + k + "' = " + v));
```

Sample output:

```
' ' = 2
'a' = 1
'e' = 1
'i' = 1
'l' = 4
's' = 1
'w' = 1
```